# How to do a visual map on the X axis in eCharts?

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I'm trying to highlight a specific part in a graph by date. The graph is dates in X axis and value in Y axis. I tried doing like this [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-sections) but I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'coord')`

This is my graph's code:

```
{
xAxis: {
  type: "category",
  data: xaxis,
  show: true,
  axisLabel: {
    formatter: function(params:any){
      return (new Date(params)).toLocaleString('pt-BR')
    }
  }
},
yAxis: {
  type: "value",
  name: 'Eficiência de Consumo (Nm³/ton)',
  axisLabel: {
    formatter: '{value}'
  }
},
dataZoom: [
  {
    type: 'inside'
  }
],
tooltip: {
  trigger: "axis",
  formatter: function(params:any){
    const seriesName = params[0].seriesName
    const timeStamp = (new Date(params[0].axisValue)).toLocaleString('pt-BR')
    const eficiencia = params[0].value
    return `${seriesName} <br/> ${timeStamp}: ${eficiencia} Nm³/ton`
  },
  axisPointer: {
    label: {
      backgroundColor: "#6a7985"
    }
  }
},
legend: {
  orient: 'horizontal',
  top: 'top'
},
visualMap: {
  show: false,
  pieces: [
    {
      min: startAlertTime,
      max: endAlertTime,
      color: '#FBDB0F'
    }
  ]
},
series: [{
  data: yaxis,
  name: 'Eficiência de Consumo',
  type: "line",
}]}
```

`startAlertTime` and `endAlertTime` are ISO timestamps like so '2022-06-13T10:42:22.772Z'. I'd like to highlight the graph between those two points. This is my graph with no VisualMap:

[Graph with no visualmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmom5.png)

This is what I'd like to do based on the timestamps on the X axis:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSl8Q.png)

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with your original question. It's just a common Js error because you are trying to read `coord` somewhere it's not yet defined.

Answer (score 0):

`visualMap` is going to color the line. If you want to color an area (like in your desired output), you'll have to use [`series.markArea`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markArea). Both are used on the [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-sections) you gave.